# Fixing "They type 'X' exists in both 'Y' and 'Z'" C# error for System.ServiceModel in LINQPad

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, linqpad

If I:

1. Create a new C# query in LINQPad 6.
2. Add the [`System.ServiceModel.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http/) NuGet package or [another package that references it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SoapCore/).
3. Try to instantiate a class from the `System.ServiceModel` namespace, for example [`System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding).

Leading to the following `.linq` file:

```xml
<Query Kind="Expression">
  <NuGetReference>System.ServiceModel.Http</NuGetReference>
</Query>

new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding()
```

Then I get a compile error:
`CS0433 The type 'BasicHttpBinding' exists in both 'System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and 'System.ServiceModel.Http, Version=4.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`.

If I create a project in Visual Studio and add the same NuGet package and code, I do not get this error.

According to [the C# Language reference for the error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0433), it should be possible to resolve by using the `-reference` compiler option or by not referencing one of the assemblies. However, I can't seem to find a way to use this compiler option in LINQPad, nor can I find any way to remove the assembly reference to `System.Private.ServiceModel`.

How can I fix the error?

Comment: I don't even have to check the checkbox for the ASP.NET assemblies, all i have to do is add the nuget package System.ServiceModel.Http and I get this error.

Comment: I tried to make a minimal example, but I didn't even consider that the ASP.NET Core assemblies could not be part of the problem. Thanks for noticing! I'll edit the question to simplify the scenario.

Comment: I notice that the Private assemblies are actually marked as "private" in the project file, could there be some kind of transitive reference that shouldn't happen, that LINQPad is making?

Comment: As a possible workaround. First add your Nuget package, then on Query Properties, click on 'Export all dlls to folder'. Then remove your Nuget package and add the four dlls from the folder in the previous step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in LINQPad, triggered by an obscure scenario. The System.Private.ServiceModel package contains a lib folder with an assembly which is required at runtime, and a ref folder with a underscore.underscore file which indicates that no assemblies should be referenced by the compiler. Because LINQPad finds no reference assemblies, it feeds the compiler the assembly in the lib folder, which causes the error.

I've got a fix ready and regression tests are currently running. The fix will likely make it into the 6.11.2 beta build, which should be released in a day or two.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you.